# How to get linter/compiler warning when comparing function without call?

Tags: typescript, linter

I make too often this kind mistake when writing typescript code:

```
class Foo {
  constructor() { }
  public get isFoo(): boolean { return true; } // getter
  public isBar(): boolean { return false; } // normal function
}

let foo = new Foo();
if (foo.isFoo) { // this is ok, getter returns true
  console.log("it is foo");
}
// and here comes the mistake:
if (foo.isBar) { // <- isBar is defined, forgot to write ()
  console.log("it is bar"); // this happens also 
}
```

Is it possible to get somekind tslinter or compiler warning for this kind mistake?

Comment: Also, I think your example is wrong. `foo.isBar` is the getter, not `foo.isFoo`.

Comment: Oh, I swap foo and bar forgot to move getter to foo.

Comment: I removed my comment in favour of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is not posibble, the syntax in your conditional is 100% valid

There are use cases in where you would want to verify the declaration of a method in a conditional statement and run some code block.

For example:

```js
class Foo {
  public isFoo(): boolean {
    return true;
  }
  public get isBar(): boolean {
    return false;
  }
}

const fooInstance: Foo = new Foo();

if (foo.isFoo) {
  console.log('Foo class has method isFoo');
}

if (!foo.isXyz) {
  console.log('Foo class does not have method isXyz');
}

const fooMethod: () => boolean = foo.isFoo; // this is also valid syntax
```

No linter or compiler will ever throw an error for either of the 2 scenarios in the above example.